# Vuejs, JTW Token From Registration Email

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Hi guys i need help with JTW token.
i do registration form with vuejs and i send data to database with axios. I need to save the token I receive on the confirmation email and send the STATE and TOKEN on the validateRegister API to complete the registration. I'm very awkward it's the first time I use vue and axios

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'Register',
    data() {
        return {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            name: '',
            surname: '',
            data: '',
            telefono: '',
            risiedi: '',
            cap: '',
            provincia: '',
            citta: '',
            privacy: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async handleSubmit() {
            const response = await axios.post('api/users/register',{
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                name: this.name,
                surname: this.surname,
            });
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the link i receive on the email
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você precisará adicionar um header a requisição do axios, dessa forma:

```
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer fefege...'
}

//Dados
const data = {...}

const response = await axios.post('api/users/register', data, {
    headers: headers
})...
```

Comment: the const headers where do I have to put it

Comment: No axios.post você passa 3 parâmetros como está no exemplo acima, o primeiro é a uri, o segundo são os parametros do post, e o terceiro é onde vão os cabeçalhos porem você deve passar o headers (a nossa constante) entre {"headers":headers}, OBS: esse é um objeto com uma chave headers que contem todos os headers da requisição